# calling a funcation with parametr in MVC php joomla

Tags: php, function, joomla

I have a model and a function in it as :

```
public function getAzad() {

    $db =JFactory::getDBO(); 
    $query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * from tablename where ag_fname = **"$ ??"** ";
$db->setQuery($query_Recordset2);
return $db->loadAssocList(); 

}
```

and there is a default.php in my view as :

```
$result2=$this->get('Azad');   
foreach ( $result2 as $row_Recordset2 )
{
<td> <?php echo $row_Recordset2['ag_azad'] ;</td>
```

I want to send a parameter to the function and in my query I want to check whether the record `fname` is equal to it or not. 
How can I send the parameter and how can I get the parameter and how can I use it in the middle of query?

Comment: You _really_ should read some database [query guides](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase) in the Joomla documentation.

Comment: is it so owfull ?? tell me what is wrong ?

Comment: i find the solution , i just need to add this code in my view instead of the first line : 

    $model= $this->getModel();
    $result2= $model->getAzad($fname);